Gamma convergence via density argument: Looking for references
I am looking for a reference or result dealing with Gamma via density argument.
Let me elaborate more my wish. I am actually trying to establish the Gamma convergence (precisely only the liminf) of a sequence of quadratics positive functionals
$F_n$ to $F$ defined on some space $L^2(\Omega)$, $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^d$.
I am able to establish the liminf only when the functionals $F_n's$ are restricted to $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ or even to $ H^1(\Omega)$ (usual Sobolev space). Namely $(u_n)\subset H^1(\Omega)$ converges in $L^2(\Omega)$ to some $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ then
$$ F(u)\le\liminf F_n(u_n).$$
It also appears that $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ when the liminf is finite.
Another interesting property of the $F_n$ and $F$ is that $ C_c^\infty(\Omega)$  or $H^1(\Omega)$ is also dense in each domain $H_n$ and $H$ of $F_n$ and $F$ respectively where
$$H_n =\{u\in L^2(\Omega)\,:\, F_n(u)<\infty\},\qquad \qquad \|u\|_{H_n}=\big(\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+ F_n(u)\big)^{1/2}\\
H =\{u\in L^2(\Omega)\,:\, F(u)<\infty\},\qquad \qquad |u\|_{H}=\big(\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+ F(u)\big)^{1/2}$$
My question is how get to liminf in general? Any answer or comment is welcome.
I am not only interested about direct answers, but also any reference where density argument is used to establish Gamma convergence or similar type of convergences that can inspire me.

I am confused, aren't your assumption implying that $H_n$ is dense in energy in $L^2$? In that case why it is a diagonal argument not working?
